# Best practice for creating a complex dict with many formulas

Tags: python, design-patterns

I'm working on a requirement that needs to take several dicts as input arguments and transform/merge them into a single dict as the output, there will be some formulas applied to the input dicts. The output is something like below: (with 50+ fields)

```
output = {
    'pnl': 100,
    'pnl_usd': 400,
    'pnl_eur': 500,
    'ytd': 200,
    'ytd_usd': 2000,
    'ytd_eur': 3000,
    'mtd': 300,
    'mtd_eur': 300,
    'cost': [
        {'prod_1': {'labour': 1000, 'material': 2000}},
        {'prod_2': {'labour': 2000, 'material': 3000}}
    ]
    # many more fields
}
```

I wonder what is the best practice of implementing this. Right now our developers defined many local variables first, and then calculate the numbers and then populate the dict and return it.

```
def produce_dict(cost_dict, revenue_dict, date):
    pnl = revenue_dict.get('revenue') - cost_dict.get('cost')
    pnl_in_usd = pnl * get_fx_rate(date)
    pnl_in_usd_prev = pnl * get_fx_rate(date - 1)

    pnl_mtd = revenue_dict.get('revenue_mtd') - cost_dict.get('cost_mtd')
    pnl_mtd_in_usd = pnl_mtd * get_fx_rate(date)
    pnl_mtd_in_usd_prev = pnl_mtd * get_fx_rate(date - 1)
    daily_pnl_gain = pnl_mtd_in_usd - pnl_mtd_in_usd_prev

    # many more local variables here
    return {'pnl': pnl, 'pnl_in_usd': pnl_in_usd, etc.etc...}
```

Is there a cleaner way of doing this, separate the calculation logic out of building the dict? Thanks.

Comment: From the information you've provided, I think a true OOP framework might work rather well for what you intend to do. Instead of a revenue dict, have instead a revenue class with their own attributes and methods.

Comment: I think you've left out a little too much detail. Can you instead provide a full example that produces an `output` dict with fewer fields?

Comment: Go with pandas ?

Comment: @AyodhyankitPaul in what way would pandas help here?

Comment: how pandas can help here? I want to know too

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga the operations he is doing, he can perform that operation with less time in pandas. If data is huge.

Comment: @chepner, the full example is rather long, more than 100 lines, that's why it looks ugly. thanks

Comment: That's why I said trim some fields. Right now, `produce_dict` doesn't show *anything* about how it actually *produces a dict*.

Comment: @chepner, edited my question, ta

Answer (score 0):

If you want to separate the dictionary building form the variable calculation a method could be to define two functions:

```
def compute_my_var(var, cost_dict, revenue_dict, date):
   if var == 'pnl':
        return revenue_dict.get('revenue') - cost_dict.get('cost')
   elif var == 'pnl_usd':
        pnl = compute_my_var('pnl', cost_dict, revenue_dict, date)
        return pnl* get_fx_rate(date)
   # ...
   else:
       return ValueError
```

The second function would be:

```
def build_output(cost_dict, revenue_dict, date):
    variables = ['pnl', 'pnl_usd', 'foo', 'bar']
    output = {var:compute_my_var(var, cost_dict, revenue_dict, date) for var in vars}
```

Yet, I'm not sure if this would be the most pythonic way. Other doubt, perhaps they could be a more efficient/optimized way than passing the inputs dictionary each time: may be as a module variable?

Comment: not quite the answer I was looking for, but thanks Ben